# Why can't an annulus be mapped as a rectangle

Tags: plotting, regions, computational-geometry, geometric-transform, discretization

The following code is used to map an annulus to a rectangle:

```
S6 = ImplicitRegion[0.1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[S6]
DiscretizeRegion[S6, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
r6 = TransformedRegion[S6, {(#1*#1 + #2*#2)^0.5, ArcTan[#2/#1]} &];
RegionQ[r6]
RegionPlot[r6, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.55}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

    r = TransformedRegion[
   Annulus[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[1/10], 1}], {(#1*#1 + #2*#2)^0.5, 
     ArcTan[#2/#1]} &];
RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.55}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

But the output is not a rectangle. It has obvious jagged edges:
[image: region]

What can I do to map an annulus to a complete rectangle?

Comment: It does not resolve the problem, but you have to use the two-argument-version of `ArcTan`, so it should be `ArcTan[#1, #2]` instead of `ArcTan[#2/#1]`. For a comparison see `Plot[{
  ArcTan[#2/#1] & @@ {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
  ArcTan @@ {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
  },
 {t, -Pi, Pi}]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your comment. In addition, I want to know why `ArcTan[#2/#1]` causes sawtooth.

Comment: `ArcTan[#1, #2]` hasn't removed the sawtooth. Just remove the `PlotRange` option and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: easy answer: these spaces are not homotopic ;-P

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It is not a continuous mapping, it just slits the annulus and straightens it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddling around...not an answer, other than that some obvious attempts don't work.

Try two half annuluses (annuli?)

```
S7 = ImplicitRegion[(1/10 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && (x >= 0 )), {x, y}];
S8 = ImplicitRegion[(1/10 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && (x <= 0 )), {x, y}];

GraphicsGrid[{{RegionPlot[S8 ], RegionPlot[S7]}}]
```

[image]

Use `ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y}]` to do the transformation. Now here is a weird one...I have to run `ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y}]` at least once outside of the transformation call or it fails. Very odd.

```
ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y}]
r7 = TransformedRegion[S7, Evaluate@ToPolarCoordinates];
r8 = TransformedRegion[S8, Evaluate@ToPolarCoordinates];
```

The `r7` region plots exactly right. The `r8` region plots wrong and jagged.

```
rp7 = RegionPlot[r7, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.55}, 3/2 {-π, π}},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
      GridLines -> {Automatic, π (Range[9] - 5)/4}, 
      FrameTicks -> {{π (Range[9] - 5)/4, None}, Automatic}
      ];

rp8 = RegionPlot[r8, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.55}, 3/2 {-π, π}},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
      GridLines -> {Automatic, π (Range[9] - 5)/4}, 
      FrameTicks -> {{π (Range[9] - 5)/4, None}, Automatic}
      ];

GraphicsGrid[{{rp7, rp8}}]
```

[image]

I could only get the `r7` region to come out right using `ToPolarCoordinates`. It then gets the range of the angles right too. Didn't work with the hand-rolled transformation as in this question. The `r8` region is wrong in the jagged edges and the angle range.

I tried this, but it crashes the kernel when you try to `RegionPlot` it.

```
S9 = ImplicitRegion[(1/10 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && (x >= 0 || x <= 0)), {x, y}];
```

**EDIT**

Some more experimenting, things appear to work fine until you get `x` and `y` values in the lower left quadrant, both negative values. For example, this works fine.

```
S9 = ImplicitRegion[(1/10 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && ((x >= 0) || (y >= 0))), {x, y}];
RegionPlot[S9]
```

[image]

```
ToPolarCoordinates[{x, y}]
r9 = TransformedRegion[S9, Evaluate@ToPolarCoordinates];  

rp9 = RegionPlot[r9, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.55}, 3/2 {-π, π}},
                PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
                GridLines -> {Automatic, π (Range[9] - 5)/4}, 
                FrameTicks -> {{π (Range[9] - 5)/4, None},Automatic}
                ]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting crashes at random even in the original formulation, when running in my laptop 11.3. I sent it on to some others with more `RegionPlot` know-how. The crashes bother me more than the imperfect handling at the discontinuity, though I think that also could be nicer.

Comment: (+11) [千金市骨](http://chineselegend.blogspot.com/2008/12/buy-carcass-with-thousand-taels-of.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround is to add a thin gap on the annulus:

```
r = TransformedRegion[
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[1/10], 1}, {-Pi + 0.001, Pi}],
                  {(#1^2 + #2^2)^0.5, ArcTan[#, #2]} &]; 

RegionPlot[r, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```